# Fatal error: Call to undefined method JUser::authorize() in mod_envolve_chat.php on line 46

Tags: joomla

What I have done is bypassed joomla 3.0 by instailling a mod for joomla 1.7 everything works but when I try and make the mod for only Registered users it cant get the jomsocial users for some reason....

here is the php code

Any ideas on what might be wrong?

```
$user =& JFactory::getUser();

if($user->guest != true)

if($envolveUseRealNames == 'real')

    $fullname = $user->name;
    $spacepos = strpos($fullname, ' ');
    if($spacepos != false)

        $env_firstname = substr($fullname, 0, $spacepos);
        $env_lastname = substr($fullname, $spacepos + 1); 

        $env_firstname = $fullname;
        $env_lastname = null; 

else
    $env_firstname = $user->username;
    $env_lastname = null;   
$env_profileImg = null;         
$env_isAdmin = $user->authorize('com_content', 'edit', 'content', 'all');

echo(envapi_get_html_for_reg_user($envolveAPIKey, $env_firstname, $env_lastname, $env_profileImg, $env_isAdmin, NULL));

else
if($envolveWhichUsers == 'all')
    echo envapi_get_code_for_anon_user($envolveAPIKey);
```

Comment: Try authorise.  Joomla speaks en-GB.

Answer (score 4):

As @Elin mentioned and as per [Potential backward compatibility issues in Joomla 3.0 and Joomla Platform 12.1](http://docs.joomla.org/Potential_backward_compatibility_issues_in_Joomla_3.0_and_Joomla_Platform_12.1):

- JController::authorize() has been removed. Use JController::authorise() instead.
- Juser::authorize() has been removed. Use JUser::authorise() instead.